# How to set pdf size using Flying Saucer library?

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer library to convert `.html` file to `.pdf` file, but the created `.pdf` doesn't fill the whole page and creates weird gaps. I tried using `@page { size: A4}` in the HTML code but it didn't work. What could be the problem? Here's the images of the `.pdf` file:

[image]

Comment: I think the problem was that the original HTML code wasn't creating an A4 Page but just a smaller container with the information, that's why it appears that way. I changed the code to make the page as big as A4 and it works well now; it still has a little of this greyish thing in the bottom but its not a big deal.